# firebase best way to handle roles

Tags: javascript, firebase, user-roles

I am newbie looking for the best solution to create roles for users in firebase (subscriber, etc). Do I create a user collection that is linked to the userid?

How do I incorporate it into a user signup:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention creating a collection, I'll assume you're using Firestore. In that case have a look a the Firestore documentation on [role based access control](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access), which shows how to use a combination of Firebase Authentication and Firebase's server-side security rules to control access to the data in your database.